# Tortoise svn Subversion Update Error

Tags: svn, http, tortoisesvn

I recently was working on an open source project...  Everything was going great for a week or two but them something happened and I don't know what, and I can't update anymore!  I know the url is correct, because I can check it out on my linux server... but when I try to check it out with tortoise svn on my windows box it doesn't work.

The error message I'm getting is this

OPTIONS of 'http://opensource.adobe.com/svn/opensource/flex/sdk/branches': 200 OK (http://opensource.adobe.com)

Does anyone know what that means.  The 200 OK part seems odd to me... it connected to the server but wasn't able to get the code? And what does OPTIONS of... mean? I've looked around, and some people were having proxy issues... but i'm not behind a proxy, and I made sure that tortoise svn is not trying to use a proxy.

If anyone could help, that would be great!

Boushley

Comment: Are you able to checkout a fresh copy into a new directory?

Comment: Nope, same error when I try to checkout

Comment: And I'm running the latest stable release of tortoise,

TortoiseSVN 1.6.3, Build 16613 - 32 Bit , 2009/06/20 09:28:19
Subversion 1.6.3, 
apr 1.3.5
apr-utils 1.3.7
neon 0.28.4
OpenSSL 0.9.8k 25 Mar 2009
zlib 1.2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out the problem was a new firewall that had been enabled on my computer.  Turned that off, and things work great again.  The firewall software was messing up the packets as it tried inspecting them.

Answer (score 6):

Had the same error

> OPTIONS of 'http://********': 200 OK

turned out to be a plain stupid typo.
The path I entered was a valid path on the server, but not a valid repository path...

=> check the path :)

Answer (score 0):

try using https instead of http. this seemed to have solved the problem for others:

http://www.svnforum.org/2017/viewtopic.php?t=5578&sid=5da45eeafa497972fe69a04f750cd2f3

Answer (score 0):

Note that you'll also get this error when using the http protocol to access subversion, but you haven't set up WebDAV on your webserver.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Subversion#Access%20via%20WebDAV%20protocol%20%28http://%29