# Maven release plugin fails when creating tag

Tags: java, svn, maven-2, maven-release-plugin

I'm trying to use Maven release plugin 2.0 to tag the version and hopefully deploy the resulting jar to the repository.

I got stuck at `release:prepare`, getting this cryptic error:

```
[INFO] Checking in modified POMs...
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "svn --non-interactive commit --file C:\Users\ME~1\AppData\Local\Temp\maven-scm-950614965.commit --targets C:\Users\ME~1\AppData\Local\Temp\maven-scm-35306-targets"
[INFO] Working directory: c:\workspace\release-test-trunk
[INFO] Tagging release with the label release-test-1.3.0...
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "svn --non-interactive copy --file C:\Users\ME~1\AppData\Local\Temp\maven-scm-829250416.commit --revision 1885 http://myserver/myproject/sandbox/release-test/trunk http://myserver/myproject/sandbox/release-test/tags/release-test-1.3.0"
[INFO] Working directory: c:\workspace\release-test-trunk
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Unable to tag SCM
Provider message:
The svn tag command failed.
Command output:
svn: OPTIONS of 'http://myserver/myproject/sandbox/release-test': 200 OK (http://myserver)

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 20 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Aug 24 19:31:55 GMT 2010
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/56M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

- The tag folder does exist and is empty
- I executed the command `mvn clean release:clean release:prepare` to be sure have a fresh run
- Every time I got the error I executed `mvn release:rollback` to have everything back to normal
- It doesn't seem to be a credentials problem, the pom file is effectively commited with the `-SNAPSHOT` removed and the scm information switched to the tag folder.

The strange part is I don't understand how the pom file is commited since I did not specify any credentials neither in the pom nor in the settings.xml file located in maven local install

I saw many people having a similar issue but with the `folder already exist` error message. Mine doesn't tell me what the error is precisely.

Do you have any ideas ?

Many thanks.

**EDIT**:
@Colin
If I browse svn://myserver/myproject/sandbox/release-test using tortoise svn for example it works fine. However if I type http://myserver/myproject/sandbox/release-test in Firefox the page is not found.
Also I think it should be ok since the pom file gets commited before trying to create the tag.
My scm section in the pom file :

```
<scm>
    <connection>scm:svn:http://myserver/myproject/sandbox/release-test/tags/release-test-1.3.0</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:svn:http://myserver/myproject/sandbox/release-test/tags/release-test-1.3.0</developerConnection>
    <url>http://myserver/myproject/sandbox/release-test/tags/release-test-1.3.0</url>
</scm>
```

I tried removing the "http:" but that didn't work.

Comment: Did you try mvn -X to have it printout even more? Sometimes this gives additional hints.

Comment: I tried with -e and -X now that you mentioned it, and I get a stack trace with the same error message repeated 4-5 times, but nothing new or helpful. Thanks for the hint though :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem isn't really maven here. It's more about svn itself. Maven stops its operation when svn send this error message :

> svn: OPTIONS of 'http://myserver/myproject/sandbox/release-test': 200 OK (http://myserver)

Are you absolutly sure about the `http://myserver/myproject/sandbox/release-test` adress ?

If `http://myserver/myproject/sandbox/release-test` doesn't exists svn won't commit anything. Just replace the **http://** by **svn://**

```
<scm>
    <connection>scm:svn:svn://myserver/myproject/sandbox/release-test/tags/release-test-1.3.0</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:svn:svn://myserver/myproject/sandbox/release-test/tags/release-test-1.3.0</developerConnection>
    <url>svn://myserver/myproject/sandbox/release-test/tags/release-test-1.3.0</url>
</scm>
```

**Links :**
[svnforum.org](http://www.svnforum.org/2017/viewtopic.php?t=5578&sid=5da45eeafa497972fe69a04f750cd2f3)
[An SVN error (200 OK) when checking out from my online repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025377/an-svn-error-200-ok-when-checking-out-from-my-online-repo)
[Tortoise svn Subversion Update Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239370/tortoise-svn-subversion-update-error)

Comment: @IceGras you should answer in comments and then edit your post, it's easier to follow a conversation like this.

Comment: Thanks a lot Colin, that worked.
I entered the scm information using scm:svn:svn:// and everything ran smoothly.
Thanks again !

Comment: @ColinHebert ... sorry wont work properly, see

[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The svn tag command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] svn: E730061: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn://henry.inter-forum.de/svn/Doku/SOA30x/trunk'
[ERROR] svn: E730061: Kann nicht mit Host ¦henry.inter-forum.de¦ verbinden: Es konnte keine Verbindung hergestellt werden, da der Zielcomputer die Verbindung verweigerte.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]